# Let's say I want 8:00PM here in my timezone be shown as 4:00PM in another timezone based on the user's timezone, how can I do that?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I will put events on my website and instead of just putting the time of the even in only my timezone, I want it to be automatically converted to the visitor's timezone, maybe from his browser's time or whatever?

Let's say an event starts at 8:00PM here in Europe, but I want it to be shown in the right timezone to someone visiting from Asia. Isn't this possible based on the user's browser or their device's default time?

How can I do that using JS?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You'd probably want the web site to provide the data (in machine-readable form) in UTC, and then the browser only needs to convert from UTC into the local time zone. The system should probably *store* the event as "local time" and "location" though, rather than converting it into UTC initially and storing that... as otherwise if the time zone rules change, you may find you're no longer accurately representing the data.

Comment: Can you put me in the right direction of which code I should be searching for?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know JavaScript, but I suspect that searching for JavaScript time zone conversion would give you a good start... maybe looking at MomentJS as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Time provided as UTC (consider the Date.now() method, with Date object as wrapper), and mostly time would be stored as UTC.
a simple .toString() will provide you with a Local Time String.
while a .toUTCString() will give back UTC Time

```js
    // Create date object from datetime string
    var date = new Date(Date.now());
    
    //remember Date.now() stores date as milliseconds passed from Unix epoch. Date() converts it into "UTC String"
    // Coverting to local datetime 
    console.log(date.toString());
    
    // Coverting local datetime back to UTC
    console.log(date.toUTCString()); // Tue, 13 Jan 2021      08:46:30 GMT
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if it's a very noob question, but I tried the code and it only shows the converted time in console, not on the actual webpage where the visitor will actually see the time. How can I do this?

Comment: instead of console.log, use a DOM element(html elements arrangement on your web page), and render this inside your element. e.g if u have a paragraph with some id (or class) " <p id="anyUniqueName"> ....</p>  ", you can select that element by "const element = document.getElementById("anyUniqueName")". Now there are multitude of steps you can take to render your date inside of this element. e.g "element.innerHTML = date.toString()". Note:  innerHTML will change the html content of the target. Anything inside of it will be completely replaced with new input.

Answer (score 0):

The time should be stored without timezone, like UTC.

```
(new Date()).toUTCString()
```

And the other user open the browser in another timezone, it will be convert to local timezone automatically

```
new Date(utc_time_string)
```